# Modulus Problems

Tags: java, modulus

In this, I'm testing if an `int` value is a whole number or has a decimal value, if it has a decimal, it slowly adds or subtracts to the value to make it a whole number. The first and the third parts work, but the second and fourth don't.

```
if(ax % tileSize != 0) {
    ax -= (ax % tileSize) / 6; // works fine
}
if(ax % tileSize != 0) {
    ax += (ax % tileSize) / 6; // doesn't work
}
if(ay % tileSize != 0) {
    ay -= (ay % tileSize) / 6; // works fine
}
if(ay % tileSize != 0) {
    ay += (ay % tileSize) / 6; // doesn't work
}
```

The ones that work are decreased by `48 / 6` each time, and the others should be increased by 
`48 / 6`, but it seems that the amount they are increased by changes each time.

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work?

Comment: Just a quick thought, but the reason it might not work is that (ax % tilesize) is less than 6, and so when java divides this number by 6, it gets rounded to 0, and ax stays the same.

Comment: @Masud I just edited the post to answer your question.

Comment: @Bucco ax is still increased, just not by the same amount each time, look at my edit to the post to see what I mean.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to do here. Let's say ax=15, ay=15, tileSize = 10. First part: `15%10 != 0 -> ax = ax - 5/6 = ax`. Second part: `ax = ax`. Third and fourth parts do nothing too. Let's try with ax=48 and ay=48. `ax = ax - 8/6 = 47`, `ax = ax + 7/6 = 48`, same with ay. In the end - ax never changes, ay never changes. Please explain what are you trying to do and maybe we will come with an algorithm for it.

Comment: what are `ax`, `ay` and `tileSize`? `int`? Did you try to use a debugger and figure out what's going on?

Comment: This is just a Java Game, and all I'm testing for is if the Player's x coordinate, (`ax`), and the y coordinate, (`ay`), are in line with the tiles, as this is a tile-based game. If they're not in line with the tiles, then the coordinates are increased or decreased so you are put in line with the tiles.

Comment: And what is the magic number `6` then?

Comment: That's the speed the player moves in. Just so that when you are put in line, it doesn't just immediately do it, and you are actually slowly moved to the tile you should be in.

Comment: Are ax, ay and tileSize integers ?

Comment: @HpTerm Yes, they are.

Comment: As long as ax,ay are int I don't understand how you can add 'fractions' to them. In the first 'if' for example. If ax= 3 and tileSize=5 -> 3%5 != 0 -> true, then you will do ax = 3 - 3/6 = 3-0 = 3 so ax doesn't change ? So how can you say it is working ? However @Max gave what is for me a clear answer, you should base your code on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this author's comment:

> This is just a Java Game, and all I'm testing for is if the Player's x
>   coordinate, (ax), and the y coordinate, (ay), are in line with the
>   tiles, as this is a tile-based game. If they're not in line with the
>   tiles, then the coordinates are increased or decreased so you are put
>   in line with the tiles.

The way to do that would be something along these lines:

```
double tileSize = 10;
double ax = 25;
double vectorX = Math.floor(ax/tileSize + 0.5) - ax/tileSize;
```

This will give you a vector in range of -1..1 which you can multiply by speed or do whatever you want to decide the movement. For example:

```
ax = ax + Math.ceil(vectorX*speed);
```

Same goes with ay axis. Also, notice that there are doubles in my formula so apply appropriate casts if needed.

Comment: +1 clear answer to a not so easy to understand question

Comment: Thank you! I know the question isn't so easy to understand, I was debating whether to even ask for help, as it wouldn't make sense to people who didn't know exactly what I was trying to do, but this worked!